# pass two parameters DDL in JavaScript / jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

This function works fine but passes only one parameter from one DropDownList to the controller. How to make the transfer of two parameters of an (two DDL)?

```
$(function () { 
    $('#DDL_1_ID').change(function () {
        var URL = $('#FormID').data('someAction');
        $.getJSON(URL + '/' + $('#DDL_1_ID').val(), function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (i, format) { });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by _make the transfer of two parameters of an (two DDL)_?

Comment: I have a form containing 5 DDL. I want to upload selected options from each DDL to a single method in the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could continue appending query string parameters as you've done with ddl_1_tc...

```
$.getJSON(URL + '/' + $('#DDL_1_ID').val() + '&myotherparam=' + yourotherinput
```

Your url appears to be malformed though. I believe you're missing the name of the first value...

```
$.getJSON(URL + '?nameforfirstparam=' + $('#DDL_1_ID').val() + '&nameforsecondparam=' + yoursecondinput
```